# Elasticsearch: count number of occurrences of a given value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, access-log

I am very new to advanced searching with Elasticsearch, and mostly use Kibana.

In Kibana, I can do a simple search like this:

```
type:apache_access
```

That turns into this request:

```
{
  "version": true,
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "10m",
        "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1613652915536,
              "lte": 1613696115536,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "type": "apache_access"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is the equivalent of a MySQL `GROUP BY` on the field `clientip`, (or maybe `clientip.keyword`??) My goal is to see which IP addresses show up the most in the access logs in a given timeframe.

Kibana does this for me in the UI, with its "Top 5 values in 500 / 500 records" feature, but that's only for the top 500 values. I want the aggregate of the entire time period.

Answer (score 1):

When you strip this query to the bare minimum and add a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation) on the top 100 IPs, you'll end up with:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1613652915536,
              "lte": 1613696115536,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "apache_access"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_ip": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "clientip.keyword",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great! However, I still need to retain some form of date limitation (the clientip field was recently corrected,) and it seems to mix our Dev/Stage/Prod data which the "Discover" tab in Kibana allows us to limit through an Index pattern. Would you mind showing me how to add both of those to this query?

Comment: Gotcha. Can you tell me what field covers the Dev/Stage/Prod flag and which date range you'd need to restrict? Feel free to use sql and I'll convert it to elasticsearch DSL for ya.

Comment: For Dev/Stage/Prod, I'm not sure how to include that in the query. In Kibana, the UI gives me a dropdown to select from, and even when Kibana shows you the query it wrote, the environment filter isn't in it. This part may need to be a separate investigation on my part.

For the date part, I simply need to limit the aggregation to rows created after a certain time: @timestamp gte some-datetime.

Comment: Makes sense. I updated by answer with the range filter -- you can add as many filters as you like into the `filter` array.